# In PHP is it possible to to grab a portion of one PDF and merge it with another?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a single page PDF with a signed authorization block in the lower half of the page. Now I have been asked to somehow grab this signed (means someone put a digital signature or image of a signature there) block and use it in new PDF pages so they can be authorized automatically.

However the library I am using (Tcpdf) doesn't support anything like this, so what I am asking is, is it even possible to grab/copy a portion of one PDF and use it to generate new pdfs? And if it is possible, then please point me to the right direction.

Comment: That sounds very dangerous for the person who's signature you are copying. I assume they know you are doing this?

Comment: By "digital signature", do you mean an image of a signature, or a mathematical signature based on encryption and hashing (e.g. PGP)? I'm guessing you meant the two things to mean the same thing?

Comment: Actually it will be the first one on most cases, if not all.